# Colors legend to be added to the Help menu?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I've had difficulty to find [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) while I was looking for the meaning of the blue background on a user card. It took me more than 30 mn, and I also tried Google!

It is filed under StackOverflow Meta but I assume it applies for all sites (most of it?).

It would be nice to have a direct link from a Question page, for example an entry in the Help menu of the top tool-bar.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the Stack Exchange sites have a lot of features like this that aren't very well documented until someone asks on Meta about them (though I guess that is a purpose of Meta). Or you find a meta post, but that's the *old* behavior, and it's since been changed. Thanks for sharing that link.

So what makes this particular question worth linking? The color usage seems to be either discoverable (happens right after the relevant action) or not critical to using the site.

Comment: My user card in this question is highlighted in gray, I have no idea why. A page with a color legend seems very helpful to me.

Comment: @mins But the fact that your name will be highlighted everywhere on the page as the user that asked the question is not really that important if you don't figure that out.

Comment: If nothing is important, then no need to explain, indeed.

Comment: Gray is the Blue of Meta. It's entirely non-critical to the core functionality of the site, though it would be nice if it were more prominently explained in the Help Center (or on [Meta.SE] rather than Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: on a badly adjusted monitor the light blue is nearly invisible on the white background